# Discrete Math (Proving by contradiction for sets)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So, the question is:
Prove by contradiction that if A$\cap$B$\subseteq$C and x$\in$A-C, then x$\notin$B.

So My process is
Let

A:{X,Y,Z}

B:{Z,Y,V}

C:{Y,Z,Q}

A$\cap$B: {Z,Y}

A-C = {X,Y,Z} - {Y,Z,Q} = {X}

So it follows that x$\in$A-C but x$\notin$B.

So I'm not sure if this is the proper way to prove by contradiction as I have never done contradiction proofs with sets before

Comment: That's not good enough. You've only treated a single case. You should also learn and use MathJax/LaTeX, it will make your posts look much better.

Comment: An example is *never* a proof.    You showed *one* case where it is true.  Are you prepared to do the same for every possible set in existence?

Comment: Also there's no contradiction.  Assume $x\in A-C$ *AND* $x \in B$.  Show that is not possible and leads to a contradiction. (Note: If $x \in A-C$ then $x \in A$.  ANd if $x$ is also in $B$.  And if $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ then ... do you see the contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

To prove $P \to Q$ by contradiction, you must assume both $P$ and $\lnot \, Q$ (**not** $Q$) are true and show that that leads to a contradiction.

In your particular case, you should start by assuming that $(A\cap B)\subset C$ and $x \in (A-C),$ as well as $x \in B.$ Then the last two conditions imply that $x \in (A \cap B).$ Can you see how to derive the contradiction from there?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone I got the answer

We assume that:

x∈A-C and x∈B

If, x∈A-C then x∈A

If, x∈A-C then x∉C

If, x∈B then X∈A∩B

But if X∈A∩B, then X∈C, since A∩B⊆C which is not possible, since x∉C

Therefore by contradiction x∉B.